# Builder Docker image resulting in running container

Tags: docker

I am trying to find the best practise to build and run Docker images and containers. In the examples below, I'll refer to [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/frdmn/docker-hellotrello/blob/master/Dockerfile).

At the moment I use this command to build the image:

```
$ docker build -t <imagename> .
```

But for some strange reason, that ends up in running *and* attaching to the container:

```
$ docker build -t hellotrello .
[...]
Step 13 : RUN ruby hellotrello.rb
 ---> Running in bf3edd441128
[2015/03/01 19:58:54.750] !! Application Debug message: hellotrello started
^C%
$
```

Is this usual? I actually just want to build the image and use a seperate command to start the container.

Not really sure what's happening here right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last command (`RUN ruby hellotrello.rb`) should probably be running when you `run` your container and not when building it. Try removing it from the Dockerfile, re-build the image and run `docker run hellotrello ruby hellotrello.rb`.

Another option is to rename that `RUN` into `CMD` and than run `docker run hellotrello` (without an argument).

Comment: That was the exactly the problem. Thank you, fellow user3538553!